# Get variable in jquery method and use it in view (laravel 5.3)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using jquery to get data from controller from controller i am returning a $user from controller method but don't know how to use it in view.

Here is my Code..

```
    <li>
<a href="#suppression" data-toggle="modal" onclick="getForm('{{ $data->id }}')"> Get Modal</a>
</li>
```

and my jquery method is

```
function getForm(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/student-forms/get-form/'+id,
        type: "GET",
    });
}
```

Controller method is

```
public function getForm($id)
{

    $user = DB::table('users')->select('name','type','options')->whereIn('id' , $id)->get();
    return $user;

}
```

I want to get above variable `$user` here in my model

```
<div id="suppression" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 500px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help how can i achieve using above jquery method Thanks

Comment: You will have to use jquery to append that information to the dom in the success method of your ajax request.

Comment: Do you want to print `$user` in `modal-body`?

Comment: @Joe please help how to append

Comment: @bluemoon see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ajax to append the data to the page when the ajax is executed successfully

```
function getForm(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/student-forms/get-form/'+id,
        type: "GET",
        success:function(data) {
          $('modal-body').append(data.name);
        }
    });
}
```

Remove the onclick event , add a attribute to the link to store the id

```
<a href="#suppression" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $data->id }}"> Get Modal</a>
```

trigger the ajax when the modal is shown

```
$('#suppression').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
  getForm(id);
})
```

Controller should return json

```
public function getForm($id)
{

    $user = DB::table('users')->select('name','type','options')->whereIn('id' , $id)->get();
    return response()->json($user);

}
```

Comment: Laravel DB Facade already returns Collection. You don't need to encode it.

Comment: is your modal opening?

Comment: then the `show.bs.modal` isn't triggered, are you sure the modal opens the default bootstrap way?

Comment: try the `shown.bs.modal` event and drop a console.log in there to see if the event triggers

Comment: what is data.name in jquery method above in your answer @madalinivascu

Comment: data is the json that comes from your controller, name is the row name from your db for the rest of the properties you `call data.type` and `data.options`

Comment: Problem is that model doe's not opening @madalinivascu

Comment: Vote for lot of help

Comment: read the bootstrap documentation on how to make a modal, when the modal works  this code should work as well

Comment: from this jsfiddle the modal seems to work with your current markup https://jsfiddle.net/96kdx5ez/1/

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jQuery you'll need to also use it to edit the dom.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/student-forms/get-form/'+id,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response){
        $('#elementToChange').text(response.thingfromyourusermodel)
    }
});
```

Comment: dear please explain what will be thingfromyourusermodel

Comment: @bluemoon `response` will be the response from your controller ajax call, so it going on your code it will contain the `name`, `type` and `options` attributes from your user model.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can use this code:

```
function getForm(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/student-forms/get-form/'+id,
        type: "GET",
    }).done(function(msg) {
        $(".modal-body").val(msg);
    });
}
```

It will add returned value in your modal-body div. Since Laravel returns collection you will need format your user data.

e.g

```
.val('name:' + msg.name);
```

By the way don't forget to add [crsf token field](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf) to your forms.